# Generated fields not triggering a script with .blur()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am quite new to Js and Jquery.

I have a problem with a script that is triggered with the .blur() option like this :

```
$('.check-total').blur(function(){

  verifCheck();
 });
```

Moreover I have a function  can create new fields with this class  `.check-total` with the `.append()`.

The above code calls a function that checks all the fields that have `.check-total` as class which works perfectly doing a sum of all the fields i have generated with `.append()`.

The problem comes from the fact thant the above code is not triggered when these new fields ar blurred.

The question is: how can Jquery circle through all fields doing a good sum and not triggering blur on the fileds I have created?

Does this comes from a possible mistake of mine or is it because of a DOM related problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler is trying to bind to elements that don't yet exist at DOM ready, you have to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.check-total', function() {
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must link up events to new objects you create.

Answer (score 0):

`$( document ).ready( function() {

```
$('.check-total').bind({
    'blur': function() {
        verifCheck();

)}
```

})`